# Error when using shap.dependence_plot() for binary classification: "IndexError: tuple index out of range"

Tags: python, shap

I am working on a binary classification task using RandomForest and XGBoost models. I have used [SHAP](https://shap-lrjball.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to explain my model's predictions, and I am able to successfully produce waterfall and summary plots, but fail when trying to create a dependence plot for a specific feature.

However, when I run the shap.dependence_plot() function, I encounter the following error:

IndexError: tuple index out of range

Here's a simplified version of my code:

`import shap import pandas as pd`

##### [Loading data...]

#### Create a TreeExplainer for the model

`RFexplainer = shap.TreeExplainer(RF)`
`XGexplainer = shap.TreeExplainer(XG)`

`shapValues_XG = XGexplainer(XGRFEXTest_df)`
`shapValues_RF = RFexplainer(RFRFEXTest_df)`

#### Trying to plot the dependence plot

`shap.dependence_plot("scata5511_1", shapValues_RF\[:, : ,1\], RFRFEXTest_df)`

Here is the full error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[213], line 1
----> 1 shap.dependence_plot("scata5511_1", shapValues_RF[:, : ,1], RFRFEXTest_df)

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\plots\_scatter.py:574, in dependence_legacy(ind, shap_values, features, feature_names, display_features, interaction_index, color, axis_color, cmap, dot_size, x_jitter, alpha, title, xmin, xmax, ax, show, ymin, ymax)
    572 if not hasattr(ind, "__len__"):
    573     if interaction_index == "auto":
--> 574         interaction_index = approximate_interactions(ind, shap_values, features)[0]
    575     interaction_index = convert_name(interaction_index, shap_values, feature_names)
    576 categorical_interaction = False

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\utils\_general.py:125, in approximate_interactions(index, shap_values, X, feature_names)
    123 srt = np.argsort(x)
    124 shap_ref = shap_values[inds, index]
--> 125 shap_ref = shap_ref[srt]
    126 inc = max(min(int(len(x) / 10.0), 50), 1)
    127 interactions = []

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\_explanation.py:421, in Explanation.__getitem__(self, item)
    419     return new_self
    420 if new_self is None:
--> 421     new_self = copy.copy(self)
    422 new_self._s = new_self._s.__getitem__(item)
    423 new_self.op_history.append({
    424     "name": "__getitem__",
    425     "args": (item,),
    426     "prev_shape": self.shape
    427 })

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\copy.py:84, in copy(x)
     82 copier = getattr(cls, "__copy__", None)
     83 if copier is not None:
---> 84     return copier(x)
     86 reductor = dispatch_table.get(cls)
     87 if reductor is not None:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\_explanation.py:435, in Explanation.__copy__(self)
    434 def __copy__(self):
--> 435     new_exp = Explanation(
    436         self.values,
    437         self.base_values,
    438         self.data,
    439         self.display_data,
    440         self.instance_names,
    441         self.feature_names,
    442         self.output_names,
    443         self.output_indexes,
    444         self.lower_bounds,
    445         self.upper_bounds,
    446         self.error_std,
    447         self.main_effects,
    448         self.hierarchical_values,
    449         self.clustering
    450     )
    451     new_exp.op_history = copy.copy(self.op_history)
    452     return new_exp

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\_explanation.py:115, in Explanation.__init__(self, values, base_values, data, display_data, instance_names, feature_names, output_names, output_indexes, lower_bounds, upper_bounds, error_std, main_effects, hierarchical_values, clustering, compute_time)
    112     base_values = e.base_values
    113     data = e.data
--> 115 self.output_dims = compute_output_dims(values, base_values, data, output_names)
    116 values_shape = _compute_shape(values)
    118 if output_names is None and len(self.output_dims) == 1:

File ~\AppData\Local\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shap\_explanation.py:773, in compute_output_dims(values, base_values, data, output_names)
    769     output_shape = _compute_shape(output_names)
    771     # if our output_names are per sample then we need to drop the sample dimension here
    772     if values_shape[-len(output_shape):] != output_shape and \
--> 773             values_shape[-len(output_shape)+1:] == output_shape[1:] and values_shape[0] == output_shape[0]:
    774         output_shape = output_shape[1:]
    776 elif base_values is not None:

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I have tried manually setting the interaction index to either be the same feature (ind in the shap.dependence_plot function call) or to another feature in RFRFEXTest_df -- this doesn't work.

Verifying that the shape of the data is the same:
RFRFEXTest_df.shape: (17, 22)
shapValues_RF.shape: (17, 22, 2)